# Sql query between two tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I justwant to create a query but not able to create it successfully.
i just want to get data from two tables but not creating right query.
here is my problem.

```
this is my first table emp with id as a primary key
id(primary key)       name
101                   A
102                   B
103                   C
104                   D

this is my second table boss with bossid as a foreign key with emp table column id
bossid(foreign key with emp table in column id)          empid
102                                                      101
103                                                      104




now i just want to create a sql query which return me a data like this
bossid    name   empid    name
102       B      101      A
103       C      104      D


In this return query 'B' and 'C' is boss name from emp table with bossid '102','103' and 'A' and 'D' is the emp name from same table emp with empid '101','104' join with bossid from bossname table and id with empname table.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have u tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Left join or Join

```
SELECT     A.bossid as bossid, B.name as name, A.empid as empid, C.name as name
FROM       boss A
LEFT JOIN  emp B
   ON         A.bossid = B.id
LEFT JOIN  emp C
    ON        A.empid = C.id
```

Answer (score 0):

See the query:

```
SELECT 
  bossid, emp.name, empid, emp2.name
from boss
JOIN emp ON emp.Id = boss.bossid
join emp emp2 ON emp2.Id = boss.empid
```